# Desktop App Converter moves registry keys

Tags: windows-10, registry, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

### **The Situation**

- The installer places registry entries under `HKLM/SOFTWARE/WOW6432Node/foo`, for whatever reason.
- The `.appx` package is manifested as `ProcessorArchitecture="x64"`

### **The Problem**

- Those registry entries are not found under `HKLM/SOFTWARE/WOW6432Node/foo`.  They're under`HKLM/SOFTWARE/foo` instead.

### **Motivation**

Why would you want registry entries under `HKLM/SOFTWARE/WOW6432Node/foo` when your package is manifested for x64?  Because the primary executable is actually x86, you are merely compelled to manifest it as x64 because of the presence of one or more secondary .exes which are x64

Now, obviously, I *could* just use the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag for all registry operations.  However, that feels like a horrible hack.  What I really want is a way to make the registry entries stay where they are put.  If a 32-bit installer makes a registry entry without using `KEY_WOW64_64KEY`, then that same 32-bit application should be able to read the entry without `KEY_WOW64_64KEY`.

**Additional notes**

If you repackage that same .appx with only one change to manifest it for x86 (Without running the converter again, this is just the`appx` packager), then the registry entries show up in the correct location.  But it won't pass validation for the windows store.

This is the most recent version. Target Image Version is 10.0.15063.0

Comment: Can you clarify what version of the Desktop App Converter you are running? Are you on the latest?

Comment: Yes, this is the most recent version.  Target Image Version is 10.0.15063.0

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting with command line parameter '-PackageArch x64'? That should get you a x64 package with the WOW6432Node/* keys in place.